# How to fix 'STACK: ReferenceError: [BABEL]' at running jest tests

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, babeljs

at running npm test i get the following error for every existing typescript class.
im using vue, jest

```
STACK: ReferenceError: [BABEL] ... Unknown option: base.cwd. Check out http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/options/ for more information about options.


A common cause of this error is the presence of a configuration options object without the corresponding preset name. Example:

Invalid:
  `{ presets: [{option: value}] }`
Valid:
  `{ presets: [['presetName', {option: value}]] }`
```